# Will adding a Node recursively work in any position of a Singly Linked List?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I learned that to add a Node to the front of the Singly Linked List the code is

```
head = new Node(data,head);
```

I am confused behind the logic for if this will work for instance, in some random index in the middle of the list. I tried implementing the code:

```
 public void add(int index, int data) {
        if(index == 0) {
            head = new Node(data,head);
        } else {
            for(int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {
                if(pos == index) {
                        //Add it//
                        head = new Node(data,head);
                        size++;
                    } else {
                        //Go to the next Node//
                        head = head.getNext();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm still kind of confused on this logic, because I feel like this will cause the linked list after the adding has completed to lose it's data. So if I add in index 5 for example, then 6, 7,8,9, etc. will no longer be a part of the linked list.

Comment: Well no, it won't work to insert a node in the middle of the list, since it changes the head, and inserting in the middle of the list is not supposed to change the head.

Comment: So would I have to make a new node to keep track of everything, and then set it equal to head at the end?

Comment: head is the first node of the list. If you insert a node in the **middle** of the list, the first node is not supposed to change. You just need to create a node, set the N-1 node's next to the new node, and set the new node's next to node N. Don't modify head in your loop. Create a local variable, and modify that local variable to go from node to node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a node to the beginning of your linked list that line will work, assuming you have something like this in your constructor:

```
setNext(head);
```

This way you don't lose track of your list. If you simply reset your head without setting up the reference to the rest of the list you will lose it.

However your index 5 example doesn't apply here. In that case you're inserting a node into the middle of your linked list, not at the beginning, so the process would be different. For example, if you wanted to insert something in position 5 you would have to set the next of the node in position 4 to your new node and the next of your new node to the node currently in position 5. See this for a more detailed explanation: http://www.mycstutorials.com/articles/data_structures/linkedlists

Comment: The second step is unnecessary, since you already pass the next node to the constructor, in the first step. All condensed, it can be reduced to `head = new Node(data,head);`. But that is only OK to insert a new node at the front of the list. Not in the middle.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't see the constructor so I just put that step to make it more clear to Shan how the rest of the list isn't being lost. But in that case, yes. And I just added an edit to clarify that it only works for adding a node to the beginning, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the Node constructor only has (int data, Node next). Also, I have no setNext method.

Comment: @Shan as JB NIzet commented above, you don't actually need the second line since it's happening inside the constructor. That is the line that makes sure that you don't lose the rest of the list. Inserting a node into the middle of the list is different though, see my edit.

Comment: @Shan, I edited my post with more information if you're interested

Answer (score 1):

You should be more clear on how a Singly Linked List works. I would suggest you go through some good article or a video tutorial. And what you are doing here is `iteration`, not `recursion`.

A `head` is pointer/reference to a node that is at the starting of the Linked List.

So, when does a `head` change?

When you insert a new node at the `0th` (assuming you are starting from `0`) or when you delete the first node.

In every other case, the `head` remains the same. Adding to the front of the Linked List would be same as adding a `newNode` where `index=0`. The logic to add a `newNode` at any `index` should be same. However, in case of adding to the `0th` index, you should reset your `head` to the `newNode`.

Your code seems to be flawed. Take an input and try to go step by step. It might help you to pin down the flaw, if any. Cheers.